# How to implement Step 5 of Firebase analytics integration Unity guide

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

I'm running Unity 2020.1.17f1

Complete noob question.
I'm using source code bought from the Unity asset store for a project. To integrate Firebase, I've followed the google guide here . https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup#confirm-google-play-version but am unsure about Step 5 where it says to put this code at the '*start of the application*'.

I think I recall reading elsewhere this step may not be needed in 2020 version of Unity. But no events are being recorded in the Firebase dashboard.

So any help in understanding how to implement Step 5?

Comment: What they mean by `start of the application` is: Put it into [`Awake`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html) or [`Start`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html) of a component that exists in your initial scene right from the beginning => It is one of the first things being called in your app

Comment: Thanks. I found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in the video below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJRZOAA63aA

For step 5 I used this code which appeared in the video:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class FirebaseInitializer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEvent onFirebaseInitialized;

    private void Awake()
    {
        StartCoroutine(CheckAndFixDependenciesCoroutine());
    }

    private IEnumerator CheckAndFixDependenciesCoroutine()
    {
        var checkDependenciesTask = Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync();
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => checkDependenciesTask.IsCompleted);

        var dependencyStatus = checkDependenciesTask.Result;
        if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available)
        {
            Debug.Log($"Firebase: {dependencyStatus} :)");
            onFirebaseInitialized.Invoke();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError(System.String.Format("Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {0}", dependencyStatus));
            // Firebase Unity SDK is not safe to use here.
        }
    }
}
```